Next js api issue in build
I developed an application using Next.js App Router, Next.js API, NextAuth, Prisma, PostgreSQL, and TypeScript. After running the build in Next.js, it was successful. I then started the build and checked the subject upload page, where the subject was successfully uploaded to the database. My application also includes a Library Page that displays all the subjects stored in the database. In development, the page works fine, but in the build, the API returns an empty response to the page. If I upload something in development, create a build, and then run the build, the data tends to show up. However, when I delete the data in the database, the page in the build still displays the data, and the API continues to serve the deleted data.
I want the build to work like it works on development

This looks like your API is returning cached response. By default, The Next.js app router favors cached responses which you can change by adding this at the top your of API file:
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

See more options in the documentation.
